# Should I add an else statement to try-except block to handle the return statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, return, try-except

I am trying to compare items in a list and find any locations where an item may be missing.

I am using a for loop by enumerating the list to compare the number within the current item with the next item and check that the number within the next item is only larger by 1. It seems to me that I should use a try-except block so that I don't receive an IndexError when the last iteration of the loop is ran and tries to compare to the next item that doesn't exist.

```py
file_list = []
for i in range(100):
    file_list.append('img' + str(i).zfill(3) + '.tif')

del file_list[50]

for i, file in enumerate(file_list):
    try:
        if int(file[3:6]) + 1 != int(file_list[i + 1][3:6]):
            return 'File missing after {}'.format(file_list[i])
    except IndexError:
        print('IndexError at i = {}'.format(i))
```

This code works, however I have read that you should try to avoid placing much code in the try block itself to avoid adding code that could raise exceptions from other locations than the portion of the code that is intended to be tested. In this case, should I add an else statement in the try-except block to place the return statement? How do I manage the if statement in that case?

Comment: Is there supposed to be an `if` on the line after `try`?

Comment: Why do you even have to compare a non-existent entry at all? Can't you think of a way of modifying the code to avoid that and getting an exception altogether and the need for a try block?

Comment: Yes there was supposed to be an if there, thank you. I edited it in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me that I should use a try-except block so that I don't receive an IndexError when the last iteration of the loop is ran and tries to compare to the next item that doesn't exist.

I think a better solution is to write code that doesn't raise exceptions under normal conditions.

Instead of comparing the current item to the next item, which as you noted will cause an exception on the last item, you can iterate starting on the *second* item and compare to the *previous* item:

```
for i in range(1, len(file_list)):
    # compare file_list[i] to file_list[i-1]
```

Comment: Or `for i in range(len(file_list)-1):`

Comment: Or if for some unknown reason you still wanted to use enumerate: `for i, file in enumerate(file_list[:-1]):`

Comment: With the exception for this situation when it is better to use a differently structured for loop rather than a try-except block, how might I go about structure a try-except block in the future to better handle an if statement?

Comment: "a try-except block to better handle an if statement" is much too broad; I can't answer that.